# How to display a value in mat-select without being inside mat-option?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my case I'm using a `formcontrolName` with the `mat-select`. I would like to display a value on the `mat-select`, but not inside the dropdown list of options :

```html
<mat-select #objet formControlName="cars" >
   <mat-option *ngFor="let f of listCars" [value]="f">{{f.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: you can use placeholder on mat-select

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-select #objet formControlName="cars" >
   <mat-option *ngFor="let f of listCars" [value]="f">{{f.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
<div>{{ myForm.get("cars")?.value }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<mat-select #objet formControlName="cars" [placeholder]="value || 'Label shown if empty' ">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let f of listCars" [value]="f">{{f.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

The placeholder attribute will show a default value in the **mat-select** but not in the dropdown.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).